# Bytearray in multithreaded environment in JSF

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, jsf-2

I need to upload a file using JSF 2.

When multiple users upload file together, the file byte array gets corrupted and then uploaded.

How to handle this in a multithreaded environment ..

I am using @ViewScopedBean with @ViewRetained for the ManagedBean..

This works fine on local, but fails on higher Integrated environments..

Can anyone throw some light on this ..

Comment: You should post some code to help us to help you.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks a lot .. Appreciate your efforts ..